# Javascript Regex to Match Wikipedia Section Text

Tags: javascript, regex, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Given the text for a Wikipedia article (see http://test.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paris&action=raw), I would like to extract all sections needing citations. In Wikipedia markup, needing a citation is indicated by `{{Citation needed}}` and a section heading is indicated by either two equals signs for main sections (ex. `==Section 1==`) or three equals signs (ex. `===Section 1A===`) for subsections.

**My regex:**

```
/(={2,3}[^==]+={2,3}[^==]+\{{2}Citation needed[^}}]*\}{2}[^==]*)(={2,3}[^==]+={2,3})?/g
```

My regex is working for many sections, but not for others, and I can't understand why.

**DOES** match:

> ===Capital of France=== [[File:Elysée Palace, Paris 2005.jpg|thumb|right|The [[Élysée Palace]], residence of the [[President of France|French President]].]] Paris is the seat of
>   France's national government. For the executive, the two chief
>   officers each have their own official residences, which also serve as
>   their offices. The [[President of France]] resides at the [[Élysée
>   Palace]] in the [[8th arrondissement of Paris|8th arrondissement]],
>   while the [[Prime Minister of France|Prime Minister]]'s seat is at the
>   [[Hôtel Matignon]] in the [[7th arrondissement of Paris|7th
>   arrondissement]]. Government ministries are located in various parts
>   of the city; many are located in the 7th arrondissement, near the
>   Matignon.
>
> The two houses of the French Parliament are also located on the [[Rive
>   Gauche|Left Bank]]. The upper house, the [[Senate of France|Senate]],
>   meets in the [[Palais du Luxembourg]] in the [[6th arrondissement of
>   Paris|6th arrondissement]], while the more important lower house, the
>   [[Assemblée Nationale]], meets in the [[Palais Bourbon]] in the [[7th
>   arrondissement of Paris|7th]]. The [[List of Presidents of the French
>   Senate|President of the Senate]], the second-highest public official
>   in France after the President of the Republic, resides in the "Petit
>   Luxembourg", a smaller palace annex to the [[Palais du
>   Luxembourg]].{{Citation needed|date=June 2010}}

Does **NOT** match:

> ===Intercommunality=== Few of the above changes have taken into account Paris' existence as an [[agglomeration]]. Unlike in most of
>   France's major urban areas such as [[Lille]] and [[Lyon]], there is no
>   [[commune in France#Intercommunality|intercommunal]] entity in the
>   Paris urban area, no intercommunal council treating the problems of
>   the region's dense urban core as a whole; Paris' alienation of its
>   suburbs is indeed a problem today, and considered by many
>   {{Who|date=April 2011}} to be the main causes of civil unrest such as
>   the suburban riots in 2005. A direct result of these unfortunate
>   events is propositions for a more efficient metropolitan structure to
>   cover the city of Paris and some of the suburbs, ranging from a
>   socialist idea of a loose "metropolitan conference" (''conférence
>   métropolitaine'') to the right-wing idea of a more integrated ''Grand
>   Paris'' ("Greater Paris").
>
> One of the main reasons for such incoherence has been the fear felt by
>   the French State in front of such a huge agglomeration and the desire
>   to tap its wealth. {{Citation needed|date=April 2011}} Since the
>   Middle Ages and particularly since the 1649 troubles (La Fronde),
>   Paris has been considered as a source of danger. The authoritarian
>   king Louis the XIVth built Versailles as a new political center, away
>   from the dangerous city crowds. The conflict between the State and the
>   City reached a climax with the Revolution of 1871 (La Commune) : the
>   French Assembly in Bordeaux decided Paris would no longer be the
>   capital city, while the Paris Commune discussed declaring Paris
>   independent of France. Since then, one of the foundations of the
>   centralized French State has been to widely distribute Paris wealth
>   while depriving the agglomeration and keeping it divided into 8
>   departments and 1 200 communes. (For an analysis of the long hostility
>   against Paris, see [http://www-ohp.univ-paris1.fr/] {{Verify
>   source|date=April 2011}} ). Of the 22 metropolitan French regions, 19
>   are regularly subsidized — mostly by Paris resources — while Paris
>   suburbs lack necessary equipment.

What is wrong with my regex?

### EDIT: New working regex below!

```
/(={2,3}((?!==).)+={2,3}((?!==)[^])+\{{2}Citation needed((?!}})[^])*\}{2}((?!==)[^])*)/g
```

Explanation: Matches any section or subsection heading (==Section== or ===Subsection===) followed by anything that isn't two equals signs, then a {{Citation needed}}-like string, followed by everything else that isn't two equals signs.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but `[^}}] == [^}]` and `[^==] == [^=]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes with sequences like this: `{{Who|date=`. The code you have for matching the text in between the title and the {{Citation Needed}}, fails when it hits the `=`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to fix my regex and post the working version later this evening.